# failed to open stream: No such file or directory in site/link/goes/here/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

Tags: magento-1.9, error, varien, autoloader

I am getting an error with my **Magento** site; here's an example of what I am seeing in my error log:

```
[Tue Sep 19 00:02:39.321749 2017] [:error] [pid ######:tid ###########] [client ##.##.###:#####]
PHP Warning:  include(WfWAFGeoIP.php):
failed to open stream:
No such file or directory in my/local/site/link/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

I am having a hard time understanding why this error is appearing, and how to fix this on my end. I recently learned that I am having a sync error with my Magento channel in Stitch Labs. Would this be related to the sync issue?

Answer (score 0):

A basic Google search indicates that the file `WfWAFGeoIP.php` is not part of Magento, but instead a WordPress plugin. Likely you have a WordPress integration on your Magento site that is getting in the way of Magento's autoloader system (using FishPig or MWI perhaps?).

The real cause is probably not pertaining to Stitch Labs. As I understand, that's an inventory management system and you likely have an integration to receive feeds that it publishes about your products. As such, I highly doubt it has created a situation where it could have affected your Magento code base.

Note that the "error" is a "warning," nothing that should halt Magento's operation. What I would suggest is that you evaluate any recent changes to your application code, specifically the removal perhaps of this plugin from your WordPress site that continues to be referenced by some other code or template.

Comment: Thank you for the information, Rick. I recently started this position, and this is the first time I am working with Magento. Their site is heavily customized, so I don't fully understand the ins-and-outs of their multisite yet.
Although this error is not related to our sync issue we are experiencing, it is good to know that we have a malfunctioning WordPress plugin we need to fix. Thanks!